# Why Mutex doesn't guarantee unique instance randomly?

Tags: c#, mutex

I use mutex to make sure that only one instance of my program is running on a server.

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, Common.MutexName);


        if (!mutex.WaitOne(1000, false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Another process is already working.");
            return;
        }
```

It works in most cases, but randomly I do see multiple instances of same application were running. Am I missing anything? The server is a windows 2008.

Comment: were they running under the same user/session?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223061/how-to-implement-single-instance-per-machine-application

Comment: @DanielA.White IIRC  named mutex are cross-process enabled. Are they limited to session/user ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think I copied this code from Internet long time ago, and it does work in most cases. I will try your link

Comment: by default its per session/user.

Comment: @daxu Try prefix the name with `Global\`. [read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Definitely read this community wiki answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/106159